# Debugging a .run file

Tags: debugging, memory, crash-dumps

One of our clients gave us a .run file for debugging.  I've never seen one of these.  I'm very familiar with .dmp files but have never used or debugged a .run file.  Unfortunately, the internet is terrible at lexically parsing .run into a meaningful query.

I know the answer is very simple, I just can't find it right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found an obscure reference to idna trace. Has anyone heard of/used this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  Apparently you have to use a Microsoft proprietary application called Time Travel Tracing which allows memory dumps to be examined both backwards and forwards.  I really wish it wasn't proprietary.

Oh well, IntelliTrace will eliminate most of this anyway :)